# select2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I get that error on the select2-script.

The full stack trace reads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
select2.full.js?ver=4.1:5830 
(anonymous function) select2.full.js?ver=4.1:17 
S2 select2.full.js?ver=4.1:19 
(anonymous function) select2.full.js?ver=4.1:19 (anonymous function)
```

I think it must have something to do with jQuery being loaded in noconflict-mode (it's a Wordpress site) but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Line 17 - 19 are:

```
factory(jQuery);
  }
}(function (jQuery) {
```

What's wrong? Using select2 4.0 RC2.

I must add that everything works as expected - but that stacktrace on the console is not nice...

Comment: This is [a known issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3175) that has been fixed in the latest master and isn't present in the upcoming final release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author fixed this error (*Fix TypeError*) a few days ago. Look this commit on Github: https://github.com/select2/select2/commit/1f62eb67e89b5b72e9aa91586c5c22d76ffc7ed9

By the way, the correct code should be:

```
jQuery.fn.select2.amd = S2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, sometimes posting here helps even if there is not yet an answer :)

Wrap line 5830 `$.fn.select2.amd = S2;` in a noconflict-safe wrapper like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.fn.select2.amd = S2;
});
```

and the error is gone. I think that must/will be changed in the 4.0 final version?!

Answer (score 0):

I had same error and fixed it in wordpress. Jquery library loaded earlier then bootstrap-modal.js lib.
If you add your script in following method:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style', 5 );
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_script('popup' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap-modal.js', array(), null );
```

Please change your loading priority from 5 to for example 90 in case you are using same method.